# How to download files using RestSharp? Specifically what do I pass to request?

Tags: c#, restsharp

Hello I am new to c# am struggling to find what I have to do in order to download a file after having logged in. 
This is my code thus far.

```
using System;
using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Authenticators;
using RestSharp.Extensions;

namespace Updater
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new RestClient("xxxxxx");
            client.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
            client.Authenticator = new SimpleAuthenticator("xxxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxxx");
            var request = new RestRequest("/login", Method.POST);


            client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
            });

            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }




    }
}
```

Now I know that in order to download the file I want I'll have to use this piece of code.

`client.DownloadData(request).SaveAs(path)`

How do I actually use this? What would be the request, and can I list path as "~/Desktop"?

Comment: I would be a `GET` to the address of the file. Use the full path of the desktop, you probably want to look at the `Environment.SpecialFolder` enumeration. Lastly remaining authenticated depends on the site, try passing another request and see what happens.

Comment: How you login to a service *depends on the service.* Assuming the session ID is stored in a cookie, then yes, passing the session cookie back to the server should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop` to locate desktop folder. Also, if you use the same client which you applied the authentication, the site remains the client as logged in because the client stores the auth cookie after login process. So, to download file;

```
var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
client.DownloadData(new RestRequest("/path/download.txt", Method.GET)).SaveAs(path);
```

Also, your code snipped lacks `await` for async method;

```
await client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
});
```

If you don't want to use `async`, just call the method like that;

```
client.Execute(request, response =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
});
```